# Is there a way to get Ionic components without Angular?

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js

I want to build an app with Ionic and VueJS, and I want to get Ionic components working in Vanilla JS, is there any library or resource to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible in the near-future with Ionic 4. Their framework will soon be framework agnostic, which means it will be usable with any JS framework or even plain JS. You can read all about it on [the official blog post of Ionic](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-2017-18-roadmap/).

Here's an excerpt of the article:

> For those that love Ionic but want to use it with Vue, or React, or Ember, or jQuery, or plain JavaScript, you’ll be able to once Ionic 4 releases.